# How can I access different $scope in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to manipulate ng-switch in navigation using HomeCtrl from route template login button. can't figure it out how can i access different $scope cleaner way without using rootscope or parent hack. please help.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div class="nav" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        <div ng-switch on="loggedin">
            <p ng-switch-when="false">please login</p>
            <p ng-switch-when="true">Welcome</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" ng-view="">
        <!-- partial html -->
        <button type="button" ng-click="Login()">Login</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="Logout()">Logout</button>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.loggedin = false;

  $scope.Login = function() {
    $scope.loggedin = true;
  };
  $scope.Logout = function() {
    $scope.loggedin = false;
  };
}]);

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you need exactly?

Comment: i want to make ng-switch but code doesn't work when buttons are outside of controller

Comment: The code will not work if you place buttons outside of your controller. you can place data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl" on <body> tag.

Comment: Use a service, https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/guide/services, they are the proper way to share information and behaviors between controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<body ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
```

instead of placing it inside div

Answer (score 0):

Use nested controller, and than you can access to a parent scope like

```
  $scope.Login = function() {
    $scope.$parent.loggedin = true;
  };

  $scope.Logout = function() {
    $scope.$parent.loggedin = false;
  };
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sgn1m5mp/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good reason to use Controller as and the vm syntax. You can read up on that here: http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scottkoland/n88sd2bc/) or updated source below.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div  data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl as vm">
        <div class="nav">
            <div ng-switch on="vm.loggedin">
                <p ng-switch-when="false">please login</p>
                <p ng-switch-when="true">Welcome</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container" ng-view="">
            <!-- partial html -->
            <button type="button" ng-click="vm.Login()">Login</button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="vm.Logout()">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    angular.module('myApp', []);

    angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeCtrl', [function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.loggedin = false;
        console.log('hello');
        vm.Login = function() {
            console.log(vm.loggedin);
            vm.loggedin = true;
        };
        vm.Logout = function() {
            console.log(vm.loggedin);
            vm.loggedin = false;
        };
    }]);

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Service to maintain the login status and other session data would be a reasonable solution so avoid scope sharing hacks.

Just inject the service in whichever scope needs to access it, and maintain state within the service.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services